# @Binding variable publishes String one character at a time

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a View with a `Binding` like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
  @Binding var myString: String

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
       // Not important
    }
    .onReceive(myString.publisher) { receiveValue in
      print(receiveValue)
    }
  }
}
```

and a Parent View:

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @State var myString: String

  var body: some View {
    Button("Button") {
      myString = "Foo"
    }
    
    MyView(myString: myString)
  }
}
```

The idea is that each time the bound variable changes `myString` in this case, the receiver fires and prints the new string. And this does work, but something interesting happens. I get each character of the new string published as a separate event when the button is tapped:

```
F
o
o
```

If I wrap the bound variable in an `ObservedObject` this does not happen. How can I get the `myString.publisher` to publish the entire String at once?

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question but can't you just `print(myString)` in that block?

Comment: I suppose that as String confirms to sequence, a String publisher is a sequence publisher and publish one element at a time and in this case one Character

Answer (score 2):

Use `onChange(of:)` instead

```
.onChange(of: myString) { value in
    print("onChange", value)
}
```

Comment: Do you know why `.onReceive` behaves differently?

Comment: `Binding` does not have a `publisher` property, and even if it did, you would need to access it as `$myString.publisher` instead of just `myString.publisher`. However, `String` conforms to `Sequence`, and `Sequence` has [a `publisher` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/publisher), which is what you're accessing. [A `Sequence`'s `publisher` emits the sequence's elements one at a time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Combine/Publishers/Sequence), and the elements of a `String` are its individual `Character`s.